# How can I change the build configuration to Release in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, publish

I'm trying to publish a Xamarin project.

How can I, change the build configuration to `Release` in Visual Studio 2015?

**Update**

I have found the solution, here it is :
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [How to: Set Debug and Release Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx) there are two ways to change build configuration:

1. From the Build menu: click Build / Configuration Manager, then
   select Debug or Release.
2. On the toolbar, choose either Debug or
   Release from the Solution Configurations list box.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question, please check, I couldn't do these.

Comment: @mrbengi: Click `Debug` on the left