# (Re-)Enable debugging for all ASP.NET projects of a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In Microsoft Visual Studio (Professional 2017) I have a solution consisting of multiple projects, two of which are startup projects, namely the API project in C# and the UI in React. My coworker did some magic to "speed up the build process" on my computer while pair-programming and is not available any longer.

Now, the debugger does not stop any more at my breakpoints for the API, only at those of the UI. I went to **Debug > Options** but I am lost where to find the tickbox(es) he ticked or unticked. Any ideas what he might have done (and how I can undo that)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908463/how-can-i-change-the-build-configuration-to-release-in-visual-studio Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration of your visual studio should always be `debug` when you are coding and testing and using breakpoints. A `release` build should be reserved for cases when you have a working code and you want to run that before deployment.

[image: Screenshot of the corresponding menu part]